# How do you add a worker dyno to a Heroku project?

Tags: heroku

How do you add a Worker dyno to a Heroku app?

Their help system includes some information: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

including the instruction to use the command line to scale your app:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1 worker=5
```

This returns the response that workers are not defined.

The UI also has a page for adjusting resources:
[image: Heroku Resources Page]

But it does not include the option to add workers.

Comment: I do have the workers in the Resources pane...

Comment: It turns out we didn't have 'worker' in the proc file.

Comment: yes, after adding worker to the proc file as described in the answer below, it then appeared in the Resources pane.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to have a worker in your Procfile and then worker dyno settings will appear in UI.

Just add

```
worker: command_to_run_your_worker
```

to your Procfile and after that you will be able to scale workers.